# Permission denied for iframe with source on same domain - Apache vhost cfg issue?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, apache, vhosts

I'm using javascript to manipulate an iframe on a page which loads content from the same domain as the page doing the manipulation.  In fact in the iframe src I am using a relative path like this:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="/foo/bar.html" .../>
```

The page displays in the iframe without problems, but when I try to access the iframe using javascript, I get this error:

> Permission denied for
>   http://mysite.com to get property
>   Window.document from
>   http://www.mysite.com.

I know http://www.mysite.com and http://mysite.com are considered different domains regardless of where they physically exist, but I've never configured anything to use the www. subdomain. So I have no idea where the www part is coming from.  My best guess is that I need to change something in my vhosts configuration.  I'm using Apache 2 and I have a very simple virtual host config file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/mysite.com/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps a CNAME/A-record declared on the DNS server that points *.mysite.com to .mysite.com more here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record you could add a redirect on all traffic on www.mysite.com to mysite.com in your app or even in javascript ;)

Comment: im not sure understand how a redirect would fix the security issue of the browser thinking theres a possible cross site scripting attack due to the domain name mismatch.  I know I can fix the symptom by modifying the source to allow the other domain, I just dont understand where the second domain came from in the first place.

Comment: basically this is what's happening: http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-domain-security-woes.html

Answer (score 0):

"www.mysite.com" != "mysite.com"

cross frame/window communication needs to be on the same protocol+hostname+port

Comment: yes i know, hence the link i posted.  my question is where is the www subdomain coming from when i use a relative url as the source of the iframe.  since its a relative url you'd think the server name part of the url would be correct.  but its not.

Answer (score 0):

As [Nick noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840235/permission-denied-for-iframe-with-source-on-same-domain-apache-vhost-cfg-issue#comment5373441_4840235), the issue is a domain mismatch. If you're on the same domain, you can do this:

1. Open your web console on the page you'll load in the iframe.
2. Enter `document.domain`
3. Make sure `document.domain` on the page containing the iframe is set to the same value.